# Eliminating extra step of creating temp table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that I execute with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT because for the life of me I can't figure out how to write it as one query, hoping someone can show me how to eliminate the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS.

My data:

`monitor table:`


`date | ip | webid | userid | compid`

SQL

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS 
SELECT webid, userid, COUNT(ip) AS total, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS uniq FROM monitor 
GROUP BY webid, userid;`

SELECT SUM(total), SUM(uniq) FROM temp;

The two sums for total/uniq after it's been grouped, are all I really need but as mentioned I'd like to eliminate the step of creating the table.

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use derived tables:

```
SELECT SUM(total), SUM(uniq) 
FROM (  SELECT webid, userid, COUNT(ip) AS total, COUNT(DISTINCT ip) AS uniq 
        FROM `monitor table`
        GROUP BY webid, userid) AS A
```

(I added a `FROM` on your definition of the temp table, since it was missing)